# jQuery.each() wont return

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I have the following loop that simply checks all "green" rows in a table called items to see which one contains a hidden input element called xxx that does not match a given value:

```
$('table#items tr.green').each(function () {
    if (myvalue != $('input#xxx', $(this)).val()){
        alert('The xxx element is not the same as ' + myvalue + ' on all green rows');
        return;
    }
});
```

But there is a `jQuery.ajax()` request below this code and even when the alert box is displayed, the `jQuery.ajax()` still runs! Any idea why?

Comment: Could you maybe show the actual ajax call then as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is to return the function outside of the each? you cant just return inside the each, each generates a function, you return now this funktion is closed, the loop still runs, you have to do something like this

```
var continue = true;

jQuery(bla).each(function(){
    if(bla == blubb){
        continue = false;
    }
});

if(!continue){
    return
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `jQuery.each` takes a callback as an argument. You're passing it an anonymous function, and this function is being called on each item matched by `table#items tr.green`, so all `return` does is return from the anonymous function.

You need to set a flag of some kind in order to achieve what you want:

```
var flag =  false;
$('table#items tr.green').each(function () {
    if (myvalue != $('input#xxx', $(this)).val()){
        alert('The xxx element is not the same as ' + myvalue + ' on all green rows');
        flag = false;
    }
});

if (flag)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: +1 this explains why my each loop wasn't working as I expected!

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's `.each` runs the passed function on *each* supplied element. So even when you decide to return from one of the functions, it will still execute the function for all remaining elements.

If you want to end the whole `.each` call, you will need to have some variable you check at the beginning of the call, and skip the processing of the function. You can however not stop JQuery from executing that function for all elements just because a single one of them returned.

Answer (score 0):

The return in your code returns from the internal callback in each method. It doesn't return from the function that contains the jQuery.each

Answer (score 0):

When you return, what you actually return from is the function executed by the .each(), the other iterations will still run. Instead, try using a flag in the same scope as the .ajax() call.